# Cant find process.env.SOME_VARIABLE in the file .env in a REACT/NODE application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, process, config, .env

My codebase has been referring to env variables using '***process.env.SOME_VARIABLE***'. In both react and node projects there is a .env file but I can't see most of the variables in the file which are being used in the project config file in this format '***process.env.SOME_VARIABLE***'

I tried process.env in node console, but I get metadata of the local environment like system setup, versions, etc. but I can't find ***SOME_VARIABLE***, or any other project-related variables in that list.

Can you please help me figure out where could this ***SOME_VARIABLE*** be defined and what is defined?

Comment: can you show where did you put your .env file and how did you set it on your project React or/and Node js ?

Comment: @ShueiYang .env is in the root folder of the project along with node_modules and package.json. But it has just these two: NODE_ENV=dev and
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true

Comment: Is the variable you are trying to find in your .env file?

Comment: Can you post the code where it is using the env variable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your env variables from `.env` file using `dotenv` in nodejs environment then `SOME_VARIABLE` will available in `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE`

Answer (score 1):

the above answer is right.

- install the `npm i dotenv` package.
- import it

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

then

```
process.env.SOME_VARIABLE
```

hope this works.